# How to change the owner of my Compute Engine so that the new owner is responsible for the billing?

Tags: google-compute-engine

I have a gmail account on which I have 1 compute engine that I belongs to my company. Right now, I'm using the free tier so I don't pay for it. However, the free tier expires soon and I need to transfer it to my boss' gmail account so that he will become the person responsible for paying for the server.

Is that possible or do I have to rebuild my whole server?

Answer (score 0):

you have to add your boss gmail account as Owner of your project, then he need to [enable the billing account](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/modify-project#enable_billing_for_an_existing_project) to your project. After he finish all the billing information all the charges will be taken from the account that your boss did setup and fill out.